# Relative Layouts Background resize on keyboard open

Tags: android

I work on a background for my app but when i open the keyboard the image resizes.

I have heard from adjustPan and so on but it doesn´t work to.
getWindow.setBackground also don´t work because i am on a fragment.

If i set the Windows Background it works , but when i go back the background is still there.
Screens:
[Correct screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5B1Q.jpg)
[Incorrect screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Rgn.png)

Comment: try this solution [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/3395978)

Comment: Have you an example , because i didn´t understand how it works :C

Comment: wrap your view in FrameLayout, set your background to it and resize contntent which you add to the FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems to be that you're using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` which resizes your activity when the soft keyboard is opened. This is what you want for sure, but background images are always resized to fit the entire element. Instead of using a background, place an `ImageView` in the bottom of the layout and put the image there with a proper `android:scaleType`, this prevents the aspect ratio from being lost.

Answer (score 0):

Add ImageView with `scaleType="fitStart"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="280dp"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@android:color/white"
             android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_background"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    <include layout="@layout/content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```